# tensorflow object detection tutorial error: ipython not defined

Tags: python, tensorflow, ipython, object-detection

I'm working off the tensorflow object detection API tutorial found here on github: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/README.md

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to run the object_detection_tutorial.py file:

```
"C:\Users\David\Desktop\ObjectDetection\models\object_detection\object_detection_tutorial2.py", line 32, in <module>
        get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
    NameError: name 'get_ipython' is not defined
```

Anyone mind pointing me in the right direction?

Also has anyone got any experience with running this on their own images? I'm looking to test it on some pictures I took around the house and I'm not sure how to write it correctly in python, it has to do with this part here right?:

```
# For the sake of simplicity we will use only 2 images:
# image1.jpg
# image2.jpg
# If you want to test the code with your images, just add path to the images to the TEST_IMAGE_PATHS.
PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR = 'test_images'
TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = [ os.path.join(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR, 'image{}.jpg'.format(i)) for i in range(1, 3) ]
```

Comment: Have you installed `ipython` or `jupyter` on your system?

Answer (score 0):

For the `get_ipython()` function call to work you need to run your script from IPython. Otherwise, there is no IPython shell instance that is currently active.
The [documentation](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.getipython.html).